# Непонятное поведение editable.replace(...)

Tags: android, android-edittext

Есть Spannable текстовое поле ввода. Для него необходимо поменять часть текста. Делаю так:

```
{
    Editable editable = getText();
    editable.replace(start, end, "");
}
```

В итоге текст удаляется, но при вводе любого символа текст возвращается в самый конец поля ввода.
Пробовал добавлять TextWatcher, в итоге:

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    //Тут текст корректный, с удаленными символами
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //А тут уже текст некорректный. Вырезанная строка добавляется в конец 
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    //Так же как в onTextChanged
}
```

Проявляется не везде, пока замечено только на планшетах Samsung с Android 4.1.2. Почему так происходит и что делать?

Comment: Полный код покажите

Comment: В основе этот класс:
https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/tokenautocomplete/TokenCompleteTextView.java : Строка 733

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перед изменением текста editable сделать `removeTextChangedListener()` а после снова добавить `addTextChangedListener()` чтобы избавиться от рекурсивных вызовов.

Comment: addTextChangedListener не установлен. Добавлял его позже и временно, что бы узнать на каком моменте происходит добавление текста

Comment: @Lexd5 А если попробовать просто получить `String`, заменить в нем и сделать `setText()` ?

Comment: Думал над этим, пробовал, но появляется проблема с тем что в Editable у нас лежит отформатированный текст (местами подчеркнутый, перекрашенный и т.д.), при приведении к String это все теряется.